# Entity Framework generates short instead of int

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, ef-database-first

We are using Entity Framework database-first for our Oracle database.

For some reason `Number(5)` becomes `Int16` - `short`

Max `Number(5)` value is **99999**
Max `Int16` value is **32767**

Problem... is there a way to instruct the mapper to translate `Number(5)` to `int32`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it, Added this to the web.config:

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
<settings>
<add name="int16" value="edmmapping number(4,0)" />
<add name="int32" value="edmmapping number(9,0)" />
</settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Recreated the Model with the `*.edmx` file and...

Now `Number(5)` is `Int32` instead of `Int16`
and `Number(10)` is `Int64` instead of `Int32`

I hope it'll help someone else in the future...

Comment: That's helped me ! Now that I have regenerated the edmx, I have Int32, but it won't compile anymore and I have the following error : `Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'XX' in type 'Model.XXX' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=5,Scale=0]' of member 'XX' in type 'Model.Store.XXX'.
`. Any idea ?

Comment: @wishper. I'm having the same problem, but it does compile! those error you're getting don't fail the compilation. I think if you use the same DLL for the EDMX and for the running application you won't be getting those/ Can you check it please? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it compile. But it only works half way. I can load data, but the creation of new data in database fail. I open a new question about that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311092/convert-oracle-number5-in-int32-with-ef4

Comment: This link could be useful.. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featLINQ.htm#ODPNT218

Answer (score 1):

Oracle with EntityFramework for me has always resulted in having a sheet of changes I have to apply to my edmx file after it's generated.

Aside from changing the column's dataType, I'd suggest manually editing the row's type in the edmx file and just remembering this is something you'll have to do everytime you re-generate

Comment: Or, instead of remembering, have a unit test that checks this.

Comment: 1. There are more than 100 columns with this problem. 2. Changing the type causes errors, and the quries don't work anymore.

Comment: Hm, that is a pain. Changing the database column size isn't an option?

I've pretty much changed all my number columns to Number(8,0) to get around this and another similiar issue

Comment: Not an option. Not my call(If it was mine I would have burned the DB already, so...)

Comment: I haven't done this personally before, but you should be able to open up the EDMX in XML editor so you get the markup and do a find/replace to swap out all the references to short with int. Basically a cheap fast way to change all the column types without using the designer UI

Comment: Sweet, voted up your answer. I didn't realize you could do that

Answer (score 1):

For `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`, I try this work, and notice the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311092/convert-oracle-number5-in-int32-with-ef4) in top post comment:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*"> 
      <edmMappings>
        <edmNumberMapping>
          <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="4" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="5" MaxPrecision="9" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="10" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="bool" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
        </edmNumberMapping>
      </edmMappings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

`

Comment: Great answer. Only need to remove Entity type from Model Browser, or directly from .emdx file