# Convert Int32 to Oracle number(5) with EF4

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4 (database first, model fully generated from it) with an oracle 10g database and I have a problem with one field.

My field is defined as a `NUMBER(5)` in my database. In my model, EF has defined it as a `short`.
My problem is that i have some values that are greater than 32,767 (max of a short)
I found this post : [Entity Framework generates short instead of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339918/entity-framework-generates-short-instead-of-int). I follow the instruction and it works, my model contain now Int32 values.

But I have a new problem :

```
Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'XX' in type 'Model.XXX' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=5,Scale=0]' of member 'XX' in type 'Model.Store.XXX'.
```

This error is always show in the Error List tab of Visual Studio. However, the build success, and it half works:

- read a value in database works
- write a value do not work : 99999 was transformed in -31073 (see edit)

Is there a solution to have it works on both ways ?

BTW, is there any way to tell entity to use int32 for oracle INTEGER fields ? It use decimal by default.

**EDIT**

While debuging step by step, I found why my value was -31073. I forgot this line :

```
dao.Value = (short)dto.Value;
```

My two values were int, but the implicit conversion in short was the origin.

Comment: It uses `decimal` for `Number` because Number can be _12.433242_ integer can hold that value. Anyway regarding your question, did you try contacting Oracle for an official answer.?

Comment: Did you use Oracle Data Provider for Oracle 11g? I use EF 4 with ODP for Oracle 11g and I have no problem with oracle INTEGER.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found how to remove the error.

I edited the edmx file in xml mode, found my field in the ssdl section :

```
<Property Name="SIT_INSEE" Type="number" Precision="5" />
```

I removed the `Precision="5"` and the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents in case anyone else is having similar problems.  I noticed if you add the following to mappings in web.config and then recreate the edmx model from scratch (delete it and re-generate from database) it resolves some of these issues.  Where simply adding the values to web.config resolved nothing (probably re-generating some of the code behind the scenes would be my guess).

```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="int32" value="edmmapping number(9,0)" />
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```